# AdMob is slowing my other view animations

Tags: android, animation, admob

When I use AdMob in my activity it is slowing down all my other view animations, introducing artifacts on them and so on. Did anyone have this and was able to somehow solve it?

**UPDATE:** I have a really old Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.2 and it was running everything perfectly smooth. Then I upgraded it to Android 4.4.4 and it started to show that crappy performance + artifacts. What could have changed there in this small update from 4.4.2 to 4.4.4??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have had this issue on a couple of our games. The problem in our case was as follows.

The game itself had a bunch of layers to accommodate all the animations, and the Ad later was on top of the game layers, this messed up the renderer as it had to cater for the ad while rendering the scene. We had to hide the ad during game play to ensure full speed animation. An alternative was to adjust the size of the animation layers to ensure that they did not overlap the ad layer, but we did not go that route as our home grown framework did not support that.

Hope that helps.